# How can I write code to view crystal report in my project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new on crystal reports and Programming! I want to make code to view my report. I search about codes in vb and angular but there are a lot of errors after run the code, I need help please where is the error in the code, this  is my code in the controller :

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data


Function PrintPdf()
            Dim rptH As New ReportClass()

            rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/ReportCY.rpt")
            rptH.Load()
            rptH.SetDataSource([CustomerReport]) 'CustomerReport is the name of table in my database
            Dim stream As IO.Stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
            Return File(stream, "application/pdf")

 End Function
```

Comment: You mixed up the C# comment characters (//) with the vb comment character. In vb it is the single quote. I have edited your code accordingly.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Mary Yeah! Thank You, but this is not the error, I added this line when I write the question here :)

Comment: @PeterKsenak In the the line where "SetDataSource: : 'CustomerReport' is a class type is cannot be used an expression.

Comment: can you kindly change : rptH.SetDataSource([CustomerReport]) to : rptH.SetDataSource(CustomerReport) and give me the feedback? Thanks